# How to send message using Organic Groups Invite?

Tags: rules, organic-groups

I am trying to use the [Organic Groups Invite](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_invite) module along with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) modules to send a message to users containing an option to accept or decline an invitation to a group.

I have set up rules to send a message to the user when they are invited. This all works perfectly, however the message does not contain the accept / decline options that I assume come with the Organic Groups Invite Module.

I am new to Drupal, and since this module has no documentation, I wonder if anyone could help me out with adding the accept / decline option to the message.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is an option you're willing to consider, but the [OG Invite People](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_invite_people) module might be used as a possible alternative for send such invitation to a group. Here is a quote from its project page:

> ... adds the missing email invite functionality for OG 7.x-2.x.
>
> When you click on "Invite user" a user is created and invited to the group right after. No registration process is needed. Invitee receives an email with one-time login link.